# Divisão de uma linha em um número de segmentos

Tags: algoritmo, matemática, animação, complexidade-de-algoritmo

Preciso dividir uma linha em vários segmentos, e todos segmentos precisam ser formados por números inteiros. Porém as vezes a divisão de  `distância` / `segmentos` resulta em um número que truncado não cobre toda distância e levado ao teto ultrapassa o tamanho total da linha.
Como divido o número de segmentos de maneira que cubra a área desejada, sendo que este segmento pode ter dois valores diferentes.

Ex: tenho `a` de um tamanho e `b` e. outro, uso x vezes `a` e y vezes `b` para cobrir exatamente a distância desejada?

Comment: E qual é o problema que tens? e que linguagem de programação queres usar para esse cálculo?

Comment: Java, mas é mais um problema com algoritmo pra fazer isso, do que um problema de implementação.

Comment: Eu geralmente resolvo esse problema com subtração dos segmentos na precisão desejada, assim o erro de arredondamento é descontado nos próximos. Em certas situações é preferível que tenha uma pequena variação entre os pedaços, mas o total coincida com a medida inicial.

Comment: @Bacco Essa é minha intenção, desenvolva mais sua ideia ....

Comment: Tem várias maneiras, uma delas é você ao fazer cada divisão, subtrair o total do segmento que acabou de criar, e dividir este segmento restante por n - 1. Exemplo: comprimento 9 dividido por 7, com 2 casas decimais de precisão: 1,29 (dá mais casas que isso). Pego 9 - 1,29 = 7,71 e divido esses 7,71 por 6. Dá 1,29 de novo (arredondando). Pego 7,71 - 1,29 = 6,42 e divido por 5... desta vez o arredondamento dá 1,28. Repito o processo dividindo ( 6,42 - 1,28 ) por 4, e assim por diante. No final, as somas vao bater com o total, e o erro distribuido pelos pedaços (há outros meios, foi só exemplo).

Comment: Os segmentos têm de ser iguais entre si? Pode haver espaço entre eles? Podes dar uma exemplo via imagem?

Comment: Os segmentos não precisam ser iguais entre si, mas precisam ser inteiros.

Comment: @pmargreff notar que o exemplo que eu dei usa 2 decimais, mas funciona perfeitamente pra inteiros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Equações diofantinas

Uma equação diofantina é uma equação polinomial em que só as soluções inteiras
são desejadas (mais informações na
[wikipedia](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equa%C3%A7%C3%A3o_diofantina)).

No seu caso, você quer resolver a seguinte equação:

a * x + b * y + c * z + ... = C

onde a, b, c... são as medidas dos segmentos que você quer; x, y, z... são as
quantidades de cada um (as incógnitas) e C é o comprimento total do seu segmento.

Para o resto da resposta vou assumir que você quer dividir o segmento C em pedaços de 2 tamanhos, x e y.

## Equação diofantina de primeira ordem

Para resolvermos a equação:

a * x + b * y = C

nós precisamos primeiro saber se ela tem solução. Essa equação tem solução com x
e y inteiros só se C for da forma K * mdc(a, b). Ou seja, C é um múltiplo do
máximo divisor comum de a e b.

### Um pouco de matemática

Agora que sabemos que a equação só tem resposta de C é múltiplo do mdc(a, b)
podemos resolvê-la. Para isso, chame de g o mdc(a, b). Ambos a * x + b * y devem
ser divisíveis por g, e C também, já que ele é da forma K * g. Logo, podemos
dividir ambos os lados da equação por c / g e depois de umas contas vamos ficar com algo da forma

s * a + t * b = g

Essa equação é fácil de resolver no computador, só precisamos usar o algoritmo de Euclides versão extendida!

## O algoritmo de Euclides

Acho que todo mundo implementou esse uma vez quando aprendeu a programar. Ele serve para calcular o mdc entre dois números. A versão extendida dele vai calcular o valor de s e t na equação acima.

Copiado discaradamente da wikipedia:

```
    function extended_gcd(a, b)
        s := 0;    old_s := 1
        t := 1;    old_t := 0
        r := b;    old_r := a
        while r ≠ 0
            quotient := old_r div r
            (old_r, r) := (r, old_r - quotient * r)
            (old_s, s) := (s, old_s - quotient * s)
            (old_t, t) := (t, old_t - quotient * t)
        output "greatest common divisor:", old_r
        output "quotients by the gcd:", (t, s)
```

Agora que sabemos o s e o t, a resposta que procuramos é x = s * (c / g) e y = t * (c * g).

Comment: A função funciona, menos para os números primos, a solução utilizada foi o teto do resultado da divisão, e com base nisso o número de segmentos foi alterado pra ter o tamanho total aproximado do tamanho correto.